# PostgreSQL WHERE IN ILIKE query

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering if it's possible to do a query performance of below query which is taking logger time than response timeout:

```
SELECT * FROM products p 
WHERE lower(name) ILIKE 'BL%'
OR lower(name) ILIKE 'Bule%'
AND p.site_id = 123 
AND p.product_type = 0 
ORDER BY external_id ASC LIMIT 25;
```

Previously it was working as in DB data was less. (Using PostgreSQL)

==> name  `varchar(255)`

I tried `similar to` and any operator but these are not giving same records and better performance.

Comment: Put an [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) in front of the select, it will print the execution plan. Usually what you don't want to see in one are sequential scans.

Comment: Your query is most likely not doing what you think it does. You need parentheses around the two `OR` conditions. If you do that, that would be equivalent to `name ilike any (array['BL%', 'Bule%'])`

Comment: ILIKE is already case insensitive, why the `lower()`?

Comment: yes, right!! ..actually i was trying in place of "iLike" ..."Like" and saw the execution time taking less time.

Comment: This is the whole query :

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS ) WITH prodExtId AS ( SELECT * FROM products p WHERE p.external_id >= $rr4$PRD4$rr4$ AND p.external_id LIKE $rr5$PRD4%$rr5$ AND p.site_id = 796 and p.product_type = 0 ORDER BY external_id ASC LIMIT 25), prodName AS  (SELECT * FROM products p WHERE lower(name) ILIKE 'PRD4%' AND p.site_id = 796 AND p.product_type = 0 ORDER BY external_id ASC LIMIT 25), prodExtIdAndName AS (SELECT * FROM prodExtId UNION SELECT * FROM prodName ORDER BY external_id ASC LIMIT 25) SELECT row_to_json(prodExtIdAndName) AS product FROM prodExtIdAndName;

Comment: Planning Time: 1.015 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Execution Time: 13644.556 ms

Comment: I just trying to increase the performance of the query. so execution Time can reduces to 4-5 S.

Comment: So you ran explain and received an execution plan. What was in it? Please [edit] your question with the details.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the products table? @PrateekSingh

Comment: Please do not put code or additional information into comments [edit] your question (by clicking on the [edit] button below it)